# PHPUnit and throwing exceptions using Reflection

Tags: php, reflection, phpunit

**I'm not necessarily look for answer involving specifically `Reflection`, any answer that works will do.**

I have the following abstract class which is extended by another class:

```
abstract class A_Class{

    protected function returnSomething(array $param = ['some_argument' => false])
    {
        if(!is_bool($param))
        {
            throw new Exception('some message goes here');
        }
    }
}

class B_Class extends A_Class{}
```

And I'm using `PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`.

I have the following test

```
/**
 * @expectedException \Exception
 */
public function testException()
{
    $method = new ReflectionMethod(B_Class::class, 'returnSomething');
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    $method->invokeArgs(new B_Class(), ['some_argument' => 'string']);
}
```

When I run my tests the following message appears:

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "\Exception" is thrown.
```

---

I've google'd around a bit, I can't really find and answer as to what I'm doing wrong. To be perfectly honest I'm not even sure that I'm doing anything wrong. The problem itself may not be with my code as much as it is with the `Reflection` class. I don't know much about it and all the documentation is kind of, uhm, lacking. It may not be able to throw the exception defined in the reflected class.

Any pointers in the right direction here would be greatly appreciated.

---

What I've tried so far:

Using `ReflectionClass` instead of `ReflectionMethod`:

```
/**
 * @expectedException \Exception
 */
public function testGetExcerptException()
{
    $method = new ReflectionClass(new B_Class()::class);
    $methodToCall = $method->getMethod('returnSomething');
    $methodToCall->setAccessible(true);
    $methodToCall->invokeArgs(new B_Class(), ['some_argument' => 'string']);
}
```

Setting the visibility to public, which of course works, but that kind of defeats the purpose.

---

In case anybody comes across this question. Don't do what I did. Even the [The guy that wrote PHPUnit says it's a bad idea](https://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html). All tested methods should be public.

Comment: Are you using `\Exception` or `SomeNamespace\Exception`? Although all exceptions extend `\Exception`... Perhaps try `$this->expectException()` Maybe this helps: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php

Comment: @AlexTartan Just tried it, using `$this->setExpectedException(\Exception::class);` and `$this->setExpectedException(new \Exception());`(which was a bad idea, got a big log of errors). Same problem. Technically the annotation `@expectedException \Exception` is exactly the same as `$this->expectException()`, but I think the annotation was deprecated in `v4.9.x` or something like that.

Comment: I think is a typo. 
Your code `$method->invokeArgs(new B_Class(), ['some_argument' => 'string']);` should be `$method->invokeArgs(new B_Class(), [['some_argument' => 'string']]);` since you have to pass an `array` of `array` in invokeArgs method.

Comment: @Whiteulver Which one? Heck I'd be more than happy if it was a typo somewhere in the code, although this is not THE actual code.

Comment: @Whiteulver Just tried it, same thing :(. `1) HtmlBuilderTest::testGetExcerptException
Failed asserting that exception of type "\Exception" is thrown.` Wish it worked tho...

Comment: @AlexTartan The manual link is exactly what  I'm doing, however the manual also assumes that the visibility of the method is public, coincidentally, it also advises that using `Reflection` is the way to go when visibility is not public. My life is a lie.

Comment: Weird, this seems to work as expected http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/90aafa5e2cd8ff8901958f22e9fe8d10ac0eb669

Comment: @Whiteulver Hmm, the problem may be with PHPUnit then? I'm not even sure at this point anymore.

Comment: Also, since you are using PHPUnit, i would suggests to use Mock objects, instead of Reflection, where you can mock and call protected methods.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, forgot about Mocking object, I was so used to using Reflection.

Comment: @Whiteulver Oh wow, that actually worked like a charm. I could kiss you right now! Post it as answer and I'll accept it asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution from using `Reflection`, since you are using PHPUnit, is to use [MockObjects](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html).
Mocks in PHPUnit allow you to mock any public and protected methods for your classes.

Comment: Thanks mate, tests are finally passing :D

Answer (score 0):

I found this question trying to figure out why my `ReflectionClass` doesn't "pass" the Exception (which ended up to be there was no `throw` in the code, my junior colleague had just used `http_response_code(404); exit;`).

But anyways, I've found another interesting approach to do this as PhpUnit MockObjects doesn't support calling protected methods nowadays:

> Please note that final, private, protected, and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit's test double functionality and retain their original behavior.

(see https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html)

It can be done by mocking/extending the original class and making new public method to call the protected one. The way it is done doesn't affect any existing code (like adding some "onlyForTests" public method directly to the original class).

(see https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/php/best-practices-to-test-protected-methods-with-phpunit.html)

The article is refering to PhpUnit, but this one could be done on its own. Here is my briefly written example:

```
(new class extends OriginalClass {                // creating new mock object...
    public function myMockMethod($param): void {  // with public method defined...
        $this->originalProtectedMethod($param);   // to recall the protected method
    }
})->myMockMethod('value');                        // calling the public mock method
```

Hope this could help someone even in different scenarios :)